# Polynomial long division properties and simplify as long as possible

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$\frac{36 x^2-81 y^2}{216 x^3-729 y^3} $$

Answer will be in the form $\frac{A}{B}$ and the answer should be shortened as much as possible

Comment: $36 x^2-81 y^2 = (6x)^2-(9y)^2$, $216 x^3-729 y^3 = (6x)^3-(9y)^3$.

Comment: That's a good hint, @njguliyev. Make it an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I suppose I will, since njguliyev won't (and since I planned to give that very hint, initially).

The big hint here is that: $$36x^2-81y^2=(6x)^2-(9y)^2\\216x^3-729y^3=(6x)^3-(9y)^3$$

What do you know about how to factor a difference of squares? a difference of cubes?

Comment: That's the problem, today my brain doesn't work.

Comment: Well, $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$. Have you ever seen that before? You've likely seen the way to factor $a^3-b^3,$ too.

Comment: I think it is (a-b)(a+b)(a+b), but i don't get

Comment: Not quite. Rather, it is $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2).$

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand what the next step is and how to solve the problem. Would be extremely relieved if you could help me. I don't understand why I don't get it

Comment: You need to rewrite numerator and denominator in factored form, and remove the common factors. That's it. (Note that there may be some constant common factors, too.)